# Swift 3 My tableView is not populatinG?

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I am wondering why is my tableview not populating? I have a tableview inside my view controller and I have tried to follow the guide however, nothing seems to show up on my tableview.

here's my code

```
@IBOutlet weak var weatherTableView: UITableView!
var items: [String] = ["Sunny", "Cloudy", "Rainy"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.weatherTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "WeatherCell")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.weatherTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WeatherCell")! as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

am I missing something here?

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are assigning tableview delegate and datasource throw storyboard or add below line into your viewDidLoad() of your viewcontroller (UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource)

```
   weatherTableView.delegate = self;
   weatherTableView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: oh hohohoho I found out that I didn't assigned theUITableViewDelegate onto my viewcontroller after adding your code in. Haha silly me! Thank you so much for you help!